# Select minimum of two rows and then sort (with no complete grouping)

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a Microsoft Access table with the following values:

```
id | C     | D   | ED         | T |
---+-------+-----+------------+---+
1  | 33105 | ABC | 2020/01/04 | 1 |
2  | 33105 | ABC | 2020/01/08 | 2 |
3  | 33102 | DEF | 2020/02/01 | 2 |
4  | 34145 | GHI | 2020/02/09 | 1 |
5  | 34145 | GHI | 2020/02/10 | 2 |
6  | 34162 | JKL | 2020/02/08 | 1 |
```

I would like to extract the rows with the **same C** but **lowest T** (with this precedence) and finally sort the results by date (ED) descending. So my expected result is the following:

```
id | C     | D   | ED         | T |
---+-------+-----+------------+---+
4  | 34145 | GHI | 2020/02/09 | 1 |
6  | 34162 | JKL | 2020/02/08 | 1 |
3  | 33102 | DEF | 2020/02/01 | 2 |
1  | 33105 | ABC | 2020/01/04 | 1 |
```

What's the fastest way in SQL to do so (the table is actually pretty large)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM tablename AS t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tablename WHERE C = t.C AND T < t.T)
```

Or with a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM tablename AS t
WHERE t.T = (SELECT MIN(T) FROM tablename WHERE C = t.C)
```

Comment: The second one is working correctly, I've just added a ```ORDER BY t.ED DESC;``` of course. Thanks!